# Deactivate SSL verification globally in Python's requests or urllib package

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, urllib3

I know that I can [disable SSL verification in Python's request package](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) as follows:

```
import requests


response = requests.put("some.host/RESTfulService/My/Endpoint/", verify=False)
```

The problem is that I use a package in which `requests` is used to make requests with it's default setting `verify=True` and I cannot access this keyword argument to set it to `False` which throws the obvious error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='some.host', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /RESTfulService/My/Endpoint/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

Is there any way to deactivate SSL verification globally in `requests` e. g. by setting an environment variable?

Comment: A bit outside the scope of the question as it’s been posed, no doubt, but why not simply fix the root cause of the verification error instead (trusting the self-signed CA at the OS level, or issuing a new cert from a trusted CA)? Longer term it’s a better solution than simply ignoring validation errors altogether.

Comment: Can you share which library you’re trying to use that wraps `requests` in this way? Some well-architected libraries will allow you to pass arguments down through to their use of `requests` for things like this. Can you share the code you’re using to invoke this library as a [mre]?

Comment: I have no access to the underlying infrastructure to get a proper SSL connection. The package I am using stems from a private company and it takes time until errors are fixed. Thus, my search for a global hotfix.